# Load firebase database list with listener asynchronous to future

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I want to load with flutter a list from realtime firebase database and wait for finished loading. I expect that

```
FirebaseDatabase database = new FirebaseDatabase();

Query _newsQuery = database
    .reference()
    .child('news')
    .orderByChild('published')
    .limitToFirst(10);

Future<List<News>> loadNews() async {
  List<News> list = new List<News>();
   _newsQuery.onChildAdded.listen(onNewsAdded);
  return list;
}

Future<News> onNewsAdded(Event event) async {
  News n = News.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
  print(n.title);
  return n;
}
```

gives the result `2` with two database-entries when i excecute it with

```
loadNews().then((List<News> newsList) {
  print(newsList.length);
});
```

But i get

```
I/flutter (19206): 0
I/flutter (19206): Title 1
I/flutter (19206): Title 2
```

That means that the listener is not async waiting. I tried a lot of different lines, but not found a solution to wait for the last query result.

I NOT want to use `setState()` in any widget, because i want to use a own singleton databaseHandler for all the widgets. For that reason is want to load the data async and wait for it in the widget.

Comment: What is _newsQuery? What are you expecting to see? It is sort of unclear how your code works.

Comment: You are right. I missed to add the query, but this has nothing to do with the asynchroneous problem. But i added the missing code. Also you can see at https://github.com/matthiaw/gbh_app/blob/master/lib/models/news.dart the datamodel of News.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think i found a solution. After a lot of trial and errors i get an idea with https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop. Used and forced with that a nested future to fill the list. Used then `Completer` to close the list.

```
Future<List<News>> loadNews() async {
  Completer c = new Completer<List<News>>();
  List<News> list = new List<News>();
  Stream<Event> sse = _newsQuery.onChildAdded;

  sse.listen((Event event) {
    onNewsAdded(event, list).then((List<News> newsList) {
      return new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 0), ()=> newsList);
    }).then((_) {
       if (!c.isCompleted) {
         c.complete(list);
       }
      });
    });
    return c.future;
  }

Future<List<News>> onNewsAdded(Event event, List<News> newsList) async {
  News n = News.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
  print("ADD: "+n.title);
  newsList.add(n);
  return newsList;
}
```

With that i get the result

```
I/flutter ( 5419): ADD: Title 1
I/flutter ( 5419): ADD: Title 2
I/flutter ( 5419): ADD: Title 3
I/flutter ( 5419): Size: 3
```

Comment: How can I modify this if within onNewsAdded I need to step through an Iterable<dynamic> from firebase? I have a few checks & balances to do to make sure I can add an item to my list so I'm stuck on how to wait until my for loop is finished to get all the data needed & return it.